# Should I store object literals inside the jQuery namespace or the global namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In trying to clean up the jQuery $(document).ready function in some of my scripts.  Instead of having lots of functions inside that function I've been creating an object literal that has properties for the functionality I'm adding to the page like so:

```
var taskPage = {

    init: function() {

        this.validate();
        this.changeActivityType();
    },

    validate: function() {...
    },

    changeActivityType: function() {...
    }
};
```

Should I put this object literal in the global namespace or should I put this object in the jQuery namespace somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global namespace is a no no!

You can enclose it in a self-executing anonymous function.

```
(function($){
    var taskPage = {

        init: function() {

            this.validate();
            this.changeActivityType();
        },

        validate: function() {...
        },

        changeActivityType: function() {...
        }
    };

    $(document).ready();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do this! If you need to expose anything to the window (which you shouldn't) do window.taskPage.validate = taskPage.valdiate

Comment: OK, I'm still wrapping my head around IIFS.  When the anonymous function executes where is taskPage being stored?  If I do a taskPage.init() in my $(document).ready() the taskPage var isn't defined.  If I assign taskPage as a new property to jQuery $.taskpage = {...} it works fine.

Comment: `taskPage` is a variable within the scope of the anonymous function, it does't leak outside it. If you do a `taskPage.init()` inside the `$(document).ready()` I have provided above, it should work just fine. No, do not assign the `taskPage` object to the jQuery object. It is **[working fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/bt4Wj/)**, how are you testing it?

Comment: OK, your fiddle cleared things up.  I was calling $(document).read outside of the closure created by the anonymous function.  Thanks!

Comment: @Shef, one last question.  What if I wanted to persist the taskPage object so I could call a setterMethod on it.  For instance I have some json that is being dynamically generated in a jsp that I want to set in a property of the taskPage object.

Comment: @bittersweetryan: Then you would have to do like Wes suggested, assign the object to window `window.taskPage = taskPage;`, but this is not recommended. There must be a way for you to pass that variable to the closure and at the `taskPage` object generation add that property.